# How to efficiently parse the number parts out of a regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

Apologies I never learned regular expressions and, perhaps as a consequence, I've never been able to penetrate R's "help" documents on the topic.

I have a list of output with page numbers annotated like:

```
val <- "Output 1: Page 1 of 1 \n
  Content content \f
  Output 2: Page 1 of 2 \n
  content content \f 
  Page 2 of 2 content content"
```

and I'd like to match the number parts of each "Page [0-9] of [0-9]" (sometimes the number of pages goes to 10s or 100s)

```
> want
page of
   1  1
   1  2
   2  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(stringr)
read.table(text = str_c(str_extract_all(val,
   "(Page) (\\d+) (of) (\\d+)")[[1]], collapse='\n'), header = FALSE, 
   col.names = c('V1', 'page', 'V3', 'of'))[c('page', 'of')]
#  page of
#1    1  1
#2    1  2
#3    2  2
```

---

Or another option with `extract` and `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = val) %>%
   separate_rows(col1, sep = "\\s*\n\\s*") %>%
   filter(str_detect(col1, 'Page')) %>%
   extract(col1, into = c("page", "of"), 
        ".*Page (\\d+) of (\\d+).*", convert = TRUE) 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   page    of
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     2     2
```

Comment: Thanks! stringr looks promising.